# Python openpyxl - recording != match cells in a comparison

Tags: python, excel, azure, openpyxl

I'm comparing data between two Excel workbooks and recording the hits in a third.

This is Azure-Provider-description.xlsx:

[image]

This is Azure-Scrape.xlsx:

[image]

And this is Azure-Actions:

[image]

And here's the code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb1 = load_workbook("Azure-Provider-description.xlsx")
ws1 = wb1["Sheet1"]
provider = ""
description = ""

wb2 = load_workbook("Azure-Scrape.xlsx")
ws2 = wb2["Sheet1"]

for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=3):
    if row[1].value == None:
        pass
    else:
        provider = row[0].value
        description = row[1].value
        for cell in ws2.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=3):
            if cell[0].value.startswith(provider) and cell[1].value == description:
                cell[2].value = str("'" + cell[0].value + "',")
            else:
                pass

wb2.save("Azure-Actions.xlsx")
```

It records the hits in column c of the new workbook, but I also need to record the lines from Azure-Provider-description.xlsx that didn't match anything in Azure-Scrape.xlsx - what do I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your I/O don't match! E.g there is no `Microsoft.Advisor/configuration/write` in the second table. Also, there is no way the code (*you're showing us*) wouldn't keep the rows of `ws2` that don't match the conditions. Please, provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and make sure the two tables/inputs are formatted **as text** (*so we can copy/paste*) and [not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: It's the misses from wb1 I'm interested in.

Comment: But you still don't provide examples **as text** and don't show the **exact** matching expected output.

Comment: So it seems you want to fill in the 'pass' section of your code in the cell value criteria check but as @Timeless states you don't indicate what you want to do if the 'pass' is reached? Your 'Azure-Actions:' screen shot shows matches, where, what, how do you want the misses recorded?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to conditionally [inner-join](https://sql.sh/cours/jointures/inner-join) the `2nd` table with the `1st` one while also keeping the non matches from the latter, you can try this :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook

wb1 = load_workbook("Azure-Provider-description.xlsx")
ws1 = wb1["Sheet1"]

wb2 = load_workbook("Azure-Scrape.xlsx")
ws2 = wb2["Sheet1"]

merges = []
for pro1, desc1 in ws1.values:
    for pro2, desc2 in ws2.values:
        if pro2.startswith(pro1) and desc1 == desc2:
            merges.append([pro2, desc1, f"'{desc2},"])
    else:
        merges.append([pro1, desc1]) # << maybe to be adjusted ?
```

---

```
wb3 = Workbook()
ws3 = wb3.active; ws3.title = "Sheet1"

for row in merges:
    ws3.append(row)

wb3.save("Azure-Actions.xlsx")
```